# How to align center a paragraph using open xml c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to align to center a paragraph but is not having any affection on the paragraph.I am using OpenXml. Below is the code:

```
//paragraph properties 
ParagraphProperties User_heading_pPr = new ParagraphProperties();

//trying to align center a paragraph
Justification justification1 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Center };

// build paragraph piece by piece
Text text = new Text(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " , ");
Text text1 = new Text(gjenerimi + " , ");
Text text2 = new Text(merreshifren());
var run = new Run();
run.Append(text,text1,text2);
Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph(run);
User_heading_pPr.Append(justification1);
newParagraph.Append(User_heading_pPr);
```

Here is how I am trying to align center the paragraph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reverse the order in which you assign text and paragraph properties:

```
User_heading_pPr.Append(justification1);
Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph(User_heading_pPr);
newParagraph.Append(run);
```

In valid and well-formed Word Open XML the paragraph properties must precede the run. So you have to build the Open XML document the same way.

This is a bit different than object models, the way we're typically used to dealing with them - the order does matter!

Comment: I tried like you suggested below but the row:newParagraph.Append(run); it is throwing an error:ERROR:Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree.

Comment: newParagraph.RemoveAllChildren(); this line worked for the error above.